# Getting error message while installing and configure Apache Tomcat in Linux (RHEL/CentOS)

Tags: linux, tomcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVBqK.png)I am getting an error msg or command not found while installing and configuring Apache Tomcat in Linux(RHEL/CentOS)using to connect with MobaXterm I am facing some errors. I follow some steps mentioned below.

1. Install tomcat package from the repository by yum command.

## yum install tomcat -y enter

2. Edit tomcat.conf file and append below line there by using vi editor.

## vim /usr/share/tomcat/conf/tomcat.conf

going to end of file and click on insert mode and we can type below line

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1026m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"

Escape :wq enter (save and quit the file)
3. Install all other tomcat packages like tomcat web apps, tomcat docs, etc.

## yum install tomcat* (note: It is showing an error msg that's why I am using the below command)

NOTE:-try this command
yum install Tomcat --skip-broken enter(note: It is also showing error msg)

Next to type Yes enter

4. Edit tomcat-user.xml file and write below (use less than symbol before starting this line and greater than symbol after) line there in tomcat-users section by vi editor, save it.

## vim /usr/share/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml

open this vi file and go to this line

to click enter

after clicking enter we can paste it

user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/

Escape :wq enter

5. Start tomcat service now.

## systemctl start tomcat

6. Set tomcat service to start automatically after reboot.

## systemctl enable tomcat

7. Add port 8080 (to be used by tomcat) in firewall.

## firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp

8. Reload the firewall.

## firewall-cmd --reload

#firefox enter

Now Test your configuration:
Open Firefox and write below line in address bar.

localhost:8080 enter

It will open apache tomcat now.

Click on Host manager

User name:admin
pwd:......
ok
back to the previous page

Click Manager App

User name:admin
pwd:......
ok
back to the previous page

Click on Server Status
Click back

(or)2nd method to follow:-

Open any browser and write below line in address bar.
ip-address:8080
(where ip-address is the IP address of your tomcat server)

Browser 192.168.1.200:8080 enter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please include the acutal error message? We can't guess what your actual error is.

Comment: added error screenshot

Comment: 1. Please always include errors as text instead of posting a image. 2. Read the error message. It explicitly tells you to install the package `tomcat` (`yum install tomcat`) instead of `Tomcat`.

Comment: Also, `tomcat` is already installed and should be ready to use